# Was Quentin ever officially placed with the Physical Kids?

Tags: lev-grossman, the-magicians

At the end of Quentin's second year he took a test to see what Discipline he would be in for the rest of his career at Brakebills.

The test came out inconclusive, and he was put with the Physical Kids by default because they had the fewest students. He was promised a second chance at a discipline the next year.

I'm up to the chapter *Fifth Year* and there's been no second test for Quintin.

When was he officially put in the Physical Discipline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, he was never officially deemed a Physical Kid. His discipline has not yet been determined.

At the end of The Magicians

> when Eliot, Janet and Julia are hovering outside his office window, trying to convince him to come to Fillory, Eliot says: "It could work this time, with Martin gone. And besides, we never figured out what your Discipline was. Doesn't that bother you?"

I think it's mentioned briefly in The Magician King, but I tried to find it, and I can't. I'll be re-reading it soon, so I might catch it again the second time.

On his [blog](http://levgrossman.com/2012/02/faq/#more-1332), Lev Grossman was asked if we would ever find out what Quentin's discipline is. He said

> We’ll find out. It’s in Chapter 2 of the next book (The Magician's Land)

So, that's something.

Comment: In Magician King, Quentin makes a comment that he is a Physical Kid in the assault against the castle.  Just before he buries the soldier in the sand.

Comment: Coming to this question after Magician's Land has come out: We learn that Quentin's discipline is repair of small objects (minor mendings).

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain the answer is no, but I'm not much further along in the book than you. I know when he first "joined" the  PKs it was unofficial. If he was made official after that it was mentioned as an aside and I missed it. There certainly wasn't any sort of ceremony.

Comment: +1: this is one of those hard answers to give, because it's _most likely_ no, but you'd have to re-read the book with a fine-toothed comb to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Read this question awhile ago and was equally curious. Upon re-re-re-reading the series, in the Magician King, Book III, Chapter 20, page 32 of 51 (in e-book format on cell so not sure how helpful that is), the narrator (?) says "Kinetics: he was good with them. He was a Physical Kid" in reference to Quentin when he is about to fight the solider near the castle on the island to the far east of Fillory.

As a side note to paqogomez, from the text, it seems more like it's the narrator saying that Quentin is a PK, not that Quentin is thinking it.